# A New Day, A New Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle

My prefix includes everyone reading this riddle

My infix is another word for putting someone behind bars but without the last letter

My suffix is what someone does before his stomach gets full

My whole is a verb

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably a long shot

> Allocate?

Line 1:

> All includes everyone reading

Line 2:

> Lock -> loc

Line 3 and 4:

> ate is the past tense of eat (However, question seems to ask for a present tense verb). Allocate does pass line 4.

Comment: Correct! Hope this wasn't too easy for you

Comment: Wow I wasn't actually sure about my solution :) Just wondering, how does the word relate to your previous infix hint?

Comment: well the way you pronounce loc is (I guess) almost the same to lock @1848